# Select multiple rows from table using Selenium in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing script to automate test where I've to select multiple rows from table & apply some settings to those rows (by selecting them in a group). For that, I'll have to select multiple rows from table, but I'm not able to select those rows using Selenium.

I tried it using following code (CTRL+select the rows), but it's not working -

```
$driver.action.key_down(:control).perform
$driver.find_element(:xpath, ".//*[@id='1']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]").click
$driver.find_element(:xpath, ".//*[@id='2']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]").click
$driver.find_element(:xpath, ".//*[@id='3']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]").click
```

Following are web contents -

```
<div id="abc" class="unselectable dataTable" emptylineuptext="Lineup is Empty" ...>
  <div class="xyz">
    <div class="def" style="min-height: 3024px;">
      <table class="buffer" style="margin-top: 0px;">
       <tbody>
        <tr id="1" draggable="true">
        <td>
        <td>NA</td>
        </td>   
        </tr>

        <tr id="2" draggable="true">
        <td>
        <td>NA</td>
        </td>   
        </tr>

        <tr id="3" draggable="true">
        <td>
        <td>NA</td>
        </td>   
        </tr>

        <tr>
        .
        .
        .
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Manually, I can select multiple rows from table.
Could someone please tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this.

```
$driver.action.key_down(:control).click("1st row").click("2nd row")..key_up(:control).perform
```

P.S : I don't know much about python selenium bindings. I hope above logic will gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be an error with your xpath expressions.  It seems to me that they're expecting an element with an id of '1', '2', or '3', at the top of a hierarchy containing two divs, then a table, and so on.  I think there's an easier way to construct both the xpath and the Ruby code.

### Xpath

First, you'll want to get a single xpath that's robust enough to select multiple table rows.  I'm not sure if it's necessary to select the `<tr>` both by numerical position and by ID, but you can make this work either way.  I don't know what kind of range you want, but you can modify either of these two xpaths to get the range you want:

**Select by ID**

//div/div/table/tbody/tr[@id>0 and @id<4]

**Select by Position**

//div/div/table/tbody/tr[position()>0 and position()<4]

### Ruby Code

The next thing you'll need to do is create an array with all of the elements you want.  The same way you can declare a value to act as a browser element in Selenium, you can declare an array to contain multiple values each corresponding to a browser element.  That is:

```
foo = $driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
foo.text
```

would be the same as using just one element of an array, bar:

```
bar[0] = $driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
bar[0].text
```

Both of these would return "NA" using your sample page above.

Now you just need to grab all the elements together, and then click on each one in turn with an "each" iterator.  You can use .find_elements for this - it works just the same as .find_element, but returns all possible matches from the page as an array.  Like this:

```
foo = $driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//div/div/table/tbody/tr[@id>0 and @id<4]")
foo.each do |element|
  element.click
end
```

Hope this helps!